# Django rest framework- Only see's one view

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm creating 4 different views for my API. However, Django Rest Framework only see's one API/URL.

The last project in my views is always the one that appears with DRF. EG if I remove "ProjectViewSet" from my views, "Location" will appear as the URL at DRF.

This screenshot provides info:
[image]

My views

```
class DataViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Task.objects.exlude(Q(tag=1)|Q(name=1))
    serializer_class = TaskSerializer

class EventViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Task.objects.exlude(Q(tag=2)|Q(name=2))
    serializer_class = TaskSerializer

class LocationViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Task.objects.exlude(Q(tag=3)|Q(name=3))
    serializer_class = TaskSerializer

class ProjectViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Task.objects.exlude(Q(tag=4)|Q(name=4))
    serializer_class = TaskSerializer
```

My URLS (again):

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'Tag', TagViewSet)
router.register(r'Info', InfoViewSet)
router.register(r'Data', DataViewSet)
router.register(r'Friends', FriendsViewSet)

urlpatterns = router.urls

urlpatterns += [
    url(r'^1.1/tag/', rest_views.TagView.as_view()),
    url(r'^1.1/task/', rest_views.TaskView.as_view()),
]
```

Comment: Do you have in your urls.py? `urlpatterns = router.urls` and have you tried putting a debugger?

Comment: Yes, have touter.urls (have updated above to show this). Please tell me the steps to debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution. As my serializers share the same data model, DRF seems to be getting stuck trying to automatically discover the url naming pattern.

Giving a `base_name` argument to each of my models solved the issue!

```
router.register(r'Data', DataViewSet, base_name='Data')
router.register(r'Friends', FriendsViewSet, base_name='Friends')
```